# Running Eureka Server and Eureka Client in Docker using spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, docker, microservices, netflix-eureka

Hope you are doing good, I face a problem and try to solve it for many days but failed. I have two spring boot microservice, one is called the client and the second is called the server. When I dockerize the microservices and run the server, it runs properly but when I try to run the client, it gives me an error. the error is like.

```
2021-12-27 11:01:45.646  WARN 1 --- [nfoReplicator-0] c.n.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator     : There was a problem with the instance info replicator


com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server

at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:112) ~[eureka-client-1.10.17.jar!/:1.10.17]

at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) ~[eureka-client-1.10.17.jar!/:1.10.17]

at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59) ~[eureka-client-1.10.17.jar!/:1.10.17]

at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) ~[eureka-client-1.10.17.jar!/:1.10.17]

at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) ~[eureka-client-1.10.17.jar!/:1.10.17]

at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register(DiscoveryClient.java:876) ~[eureka-client-1.10.17.jar!/:1.10.17]

at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:121) ~[eureka-client-1.10.17.jar!/:1.10.17]

at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator$1.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:101) ~[eureka-client-1.10.17.jar!/:1.10.17]

at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]

at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]

at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]

at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135) ~[na:na]

at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]

at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) ~[na:na]
```

**The Server application.yml file is;**

```
server.port: 8761

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: eurekaserver
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false

spring:
  application:
    name: EUREKA-SERVER
```

**While the client application.yml file is like;**

```
server:
  port: 8080


spring:
  application:
    name: EUREKA-CLIENT

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: eurekaclient
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

I try `defaultZone: http://eurekaserver:8761/eureka`. but got the same error.

The docker file of Client is:

```
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} eurekaclient.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/eurekaclient.jar"]
```

**Thanks in advance :)**

Comment: When do you see the above issue - during client startup? Assuming you are able to start both the service, what does http://localhost:8761/ show?

Comment: the localhost:8761 show my server, which run correctly.

Comment: Does it show registered clients?

Comment: NO, When i run the client container, i see the above error in the log file.  `There was a problem with the instance info replicator`

Comment: The client is trying to find the server, but it fail, and i don't no why.

Comment: It's a docker network configuration thing. Since defaultZone points to `localhost`, did you start the server container with 8761 port open?

Comment: Yes, http://localhost:8761, works for server

Comment: I think your problem with the startup order of the containers. You may want to check out: https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

Comment: I build the microservice according  to the documentation, i update my question to add the docker file code.

Comment: Perhaps your client is trying to find a server inside it's container instead of on the host machine.

Comment: yea, I hope so, but do we avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:
The label after service-url property (which can be aliased as serviceUrl in YML) is a HashMap KEY, not a property label. So it has to be kept as a Camel Case tag in any ways!

eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://[myIP@]:8787/eureka

Comment: How do we get the IP.

Answer (score 0):

you can't register to eureka server by passing localhost.

what you can do, give the container name in place of localhost and create one network, and while running the images specify the network as well.

Please follow the below steps.

**Let's say your eureka images name is -> eureka-server**

first, create a network using the below command :

**docker create network springcloud-ms**

run the eureka container and specify the network as well like below :

**docker run --name eureka-container -p 8761:8761 --network springcloud-ms eureka-server**

change the application.yml of eureka client as below :

**server:
port: 8080
spring:
application:
name: EUREKA-CLIENT
eureka:
instance:
hostname: eurekaclient
client:
serviceUrl:
defaultZone: http://eureka-container:8761/eureka**

then run the client image. Let's say your client image name is client-service then use the below command:

**docker run --name client-container -p 8080:8080 --network springcloud-ms client-service**

Comment: Conceptually it should be correct , though I have not tried .

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's still an issue for anybody but in my case (docker containers), I had to take care of the serviceUrl in the client's application.properties. As @Qkhattak mentioned above, watch out for camel-case defaultZone!

Previously I was using (Not working):

```
eureka.client.service-url.default-zone=${EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICE_URL:http://localhost:8761/eureka}
```

Now using (Works perfectly):

```
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=${EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICE_URL:http://localhost:8761/eureka}
```